# UI missing in Flutter APK

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, apk, flutter-build

I've been trying since two days to resolve this weird issue.

In debug mode my app running good but in release `apk` UI not rendering. I've checked all possible solutions but can't fix it. As some UI is also missing from first screen.

Here is My app

[image]

Here is my First screen code

```
   class ChooseLanguage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChooseLanguage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChooseLanguage> createState() => _ChooseLanguageState();
}

class _ChooseLanguageState extends State<ChooseLanguage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: BackgroundImage(
          image: 'assets/images/mainBg.png',
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset("assets/images/marhaba.png"),
                SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height150),
                const BigText(
                    text: 'Choose your language', color: Colors.white),
                SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10),
                Image.asset("assets/images/choose_lang.png",
                    width: Dimensions.width230),
                SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height20),
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Get.to(() => const LoginAs());
                          },
                          child: const Text('English')),
                      ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Arabic')),
                    ])
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After Tapping On English `Button` Code

```
class LoginAs extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginAs({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginAs> createState() => _LoginAsState();
}

class _LoginAsState extends State<LoginAs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: BackgroundImage(
        image: 'assets/images/mainBg.png',
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const BigText(text: 'Are You', color: Colors.white),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(() => const BottomNav());
                },
                child: const BigRoundedContainer(
                    image: "assets/images/visitor.png", text: 'Visitor'),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.to(() => const ChooseAuth());
                    },
                    child: const BigRoundedContainer(
                        image: "assets/images/agency.png", text: 'Agency'),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Get.to(() => const ChooseAuth());
                    },
                    child: const BigRoundedContainer(
                        image: "assets/images/freelancer.png",
                        text: 'Freelancer'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height:40),
              Image.asset("assets/images/enjoy.png", width: 200)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**BigRoundedContainer.dart**

```
   class BigRoundedContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String image, text;

  const BigRoundedContainer({Key? key, required this.image, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: Dimensions.width130,
      height: Dimensions.height130,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius30),
          color: Colors.white),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: Dimensions.height10),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Image.asset(image, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
          ),
          SmallText(text: text, size: Dimensions.height20),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Edited**

**Logcat error**

```
    Please configure Android SDK
2022-07-22 14:49:03.128 16923-16948/com.example.media_adv E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
2022-07-22 14:49:04.129 16923-16948/com.example.media_adv E/: [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0102]
```

error in logcat `Please configure Android SDK`

Here is my screenshot of project structure
[image]

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app? most of the part is image, does it render regular widget like Text, also if it includes getx consider including on tag section.

Comment: I've already tried this.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Kindly help. I've to generate APK today

Comment: Are you testing on `Huawei`

Comment: yes testing on `Huawei`

Comment: there are some on this device side, try on different device. also you can send your project to your teammate and test on their side.

Comment: I've already checked this

Comment: @YeasinSheikh hi, I've found the solution but I don't know the logic behind of it. If you can determine I'll be thankful to you. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why do you need delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My UI wasn't shown in `release APK` but in `build APK` it was ok. In first screen, which I've put in the question, I've a `Text()` and `image`, even the `Text()` wasn't displayed. So I resolve this issue by adding these lines in the `main.dart`. After that my UI shown. I don't know why should I've to delay it. If anyone can explain it I'll be grateful for him/her. Thanks.

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Hours on this. About explanation, I think this can be useful: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99680.